# Running a RPC node, Total 0 RPC nodes found

Tags: rpc

Our RPC nodes suddenly lost track on the RCP nodes:

[2024-02-07T05:46:22.284373328Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Searching for an RPC service with shred version 56177 (Retrying: Wait for known rpc peers)...
[2024-02-07T05:46:22.284457881Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Total 0 RPC nodes found. 0 known, 0 blacklisted

If removing the flag --only-known-rpc, it would return no available snapshots.

Can you please help?

Comment: This is the error after removing --only-known-rpc:

`[2024-02-07T05:51:19.319672392Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Searching for an RPC service with shred version 56177 (Retrying: No snapshots available)...
[2024-02-07T05:51:19.319730857Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Total 64 RPC nodes found. 0 known, 0 blacklisted`

Comment: oh seems I had to specify the shred version as 50093, where can we get the valid shred version for mainnet?

Answer (score 1):

So the shred is used to ensure you are on the right network. I am unsure what network shred 56177 is for, but it is not mainnet.

The correct shred number for mainnet is 50093. You can see it in the [documentation for the latest cluster restart](https://github.com/laine-sa/cluster_restart/blob/master/README.md#network-has-restarted---disregard-these-instructions), but unfortunately, it is not in the [official clusters docs](https://docs.solanalabs.com/clusters/available).

Perhaps this is something @jacob-creech can help get sorted?